# Fedora 39 w/ toolbox trying to run OpenWebStart and open .jnlp file

Tags: java, fedora, java-web-start, java-ws, openwebstart

Using Fedora 39 w/ toolbox trying to run OpenWebStart and open .jnlp file.

I created a toolbox and downloaded:

- java-latest-openjdk and
- OpenWebStart from https://github.com/fatihusta/OpenWebStartRPM/releases.

Both packages installed as verified by `dnf list installed`. I find both.

But I cannot call the version of OpenWebStart. It is not `ows` and not `openwebstart` `-version`. Why not?

And how do I run it in my toolbox?

Also I have a `.jnlp` file that I wish to open and run inside my toolbox. With `javaws` nothing happens, response is `command not found`. What am I missing?